# Is there a way to persist lambdas in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, persistence, java-8

The scenario is:

`interface MyInterface<S,T> {
       Function<S,T> myHighOrderFunction(Object... parameters);
}`

I call:

`Function<A,B> f = someImplementation.myHighOrderFunction(...);`

And would now like to be able to store f (which, as I understand it, is a class) to be loaded in a future run.

Comment: using a blob we can do it, cant we? not so sure,  just a guess

Comment: The duplicate of this doesn't say how you'd go about deserialising the lambda. Would it help?